# Java Swing Graphics and Events

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a simple game which displays circles on a frame and when clicked the circle should disappear. I am learning how Java Swing works and managed to draw a circle (Wow such an achievement) and figured out how events work. I added an mouseListener to the circle and when clicked for now I want a to get a console log that it has been clicked but the end result is not as expected. No matter where I click I always get the "click" console log. When I try to add a listener to a JButton for example I get the end result. Are events different for graphics?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class CirclePop {

    JFrame frame;
    Circle circle;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CirclePop circlePop = new CirclePop();
        circlePop.drawFrame();
    }

    public void drawFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        circle  = new Circle();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(circle);

        circle.addMouseListener(new Click());

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Click implements MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Circle extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(150, 140, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: What bounds does the Circle have?
I have found out - kind of - that the bounds of the JPanel and where you draw the graphics on are not exactly the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the MouseListener interface indeed, and after a mouse click, you have to check whether the mouse position is contained in the region of your circle. You could do this manually, by comparing coordinates, but this could be a bit too much work. 
I think it's easier to rather create a Shape object(Infact this is a good time to learn about it since you're just starting out) that you fill with the respective color, and then just check whether the circle contains the mouse position.

Also, check out the [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) class docs when you've got some spare time.

I've gone ahead and made changes to your code, it now uses an instance of `Shape` class to create a circle.
Also, instead of implementing the `MouseListener` interface, I recommend extending `MouseAdapter` since you're not actually providing any meaningful implementation to any method of the interface except the `mousePressed()` method.

Lastly, notice the `shape.contains(event.getPoint())` in the `mousePressed()` method, that is what does the trick for checking the coordinates. 
The rest of the code should be familiar.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class CirclePop {

    JFrame frame;
    Circle circle;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CirclePop circlePop = new CirclePop();
        circlePop.drawFrame();
    }

    public void drawFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        circle  = new Circle();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(circle);

        circle.addMouseListener(new Click());

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Click extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (circle.shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Circle extends JPanel {
    Shape shape;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 140, 30, 30);
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fill(shape);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may want to `extend MouseAdapter` instead of implementing `MouseListener`. This way you don't have "implement" all these empty methods.

Then, in your `mousePressed` method you just have to calculate if the click happened inside the circle. This is basically just Pythagoras:

```java
static class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final Circle circle;

    public ClickListener(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int centerX = circle.getCenterX();
        int centerY = circle.getCenterY();
        int radius = circle.getRadius();
        int clickX = e.getX();
        int clickY = e.getY();

        // inside circle: (clickX - centerX)^2 + (clickY - centerY)^2 < radius^2
        double xSquare = Math.pow(clickX - centerX, 2);
        double ySquare = Math.pow(clickY - centerY, 2);

        if (xSquare + ySquare < radius * radius) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

I've added some fields to `Circle` class to get access to the properties you need for the calculation:

```java
class Circle extends JPanel {
    private final int radius = 30;
    private final int centerX = 150;
    private final int centerY = 140;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(centerX, centerY, radius, radius);
    }
    // getter, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, this isn't going to be short

Let's start with ....

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    circle  = new Circle();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(circle);

    circle.addMouseListener(new Click());

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Okay, seems simple enough, but, one thing you've missed is the fact that `JFrame`, by default, uses a `BorderLayout` - this means, it will make the child component (and the centre/default position) fill all the available space of the frames viewable space

You can see this if you do something like...

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    circle  = new Circle();
    circle.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

You will now see that the `Circle` component occupies the entire frame, so when you click on it, you're clicking the `Circle` component itself.

This isn't bad, but, you might want to change tact a little.  Instead of adding the `MouseListener` independently of the `Circle`, have the `Circle` component make use of its own `MouseListener`, for example...

```
class Circle extends JPanel {

    public Circle() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // More to come...
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(150, 140, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

This means you get to control much of the logic internally to the class, makes it easier to access some of the more critical information without needing to make a bunch of, potentially, dangerous casts.

So, now we just need to add the logic in to determine if the mouse was clicked within the desirable location or not...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point point = e.getPoint();
    if (point.x >= 150 && point.x <= 150 + 30 && point.y >= 140 && point.y <= 140 + 30) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me :(");
    }
}
```

Okay, that's ... basic

We can simplify it a little and make use of the available functionality within the wider API by making use of the "shapes" API, for example...

```
class Circle extends JPanel {
    
    private Ellipse2D dot = new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 140, 30, 30);

    public Circle() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point point = e.getPoint();
                if (dot.contains(point)) {
                    System.out.println("You clicked me :(");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(dot);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The benefit of this, apart from `contains`, is we can change the position of the shape relatively easily and our `if` statement contains to work

I do, highly, recommend also having a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/TOC.html)
- [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html)

Comment: Your calculation if the point is inside the circle is not correct. You're testing if the point is within some square with side length 30, not if it's inside a circle, don't you?

Comment: @AlexR I wasn't going for "super accurate" - I was going for "basic" with "use the available API" - For "most simple" applications, a "square" would suffice - unless it's super large, most users wouldn't notice ;)